# Zend Framework 1.12 - Zend Form File element triggering wrong validation messages

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I have looked through similar answers but couldn't find any solution.

I have a file element in one of my forms. This element is defined below.

```
$file = $this->createElement('file', 'templateFile');
$file->setAttrib('id', 'templateFile')
     ->setAttrib('class', 'form-control')
     ->setAttrib('placeholder', 'File containing template headers')
     ->setLabel('Template File <span class="glyphicons glyphicons-sheriffs_star requiredFlag"></span>')
     ->setRequired(true)
     ->addValidator('NotEmpty', false)
     ->addValidator('Count', false, 1)
     ->addValidator('Size', false, '1MB')
     ->addValidator("Extension", false, array('csv', 'txt'))
     ->addFilter('StringTrim');

$file->getValidator('NotEmpty')->setMessage('Please select a template file');
$file->getValidator('Count')->setMessage(' Please upload one file at a time');
$file->getValidator('Size')->setMessage('File exceeds the upload limit of 1 MB');
$file->getValidator('Extension')->setMessage('Invalid file extension. Only CSV and TXT files are allowed');
```

I am using custom error messages with this element and this is what is causing problems.

When I submit a form without choosing a file rather then triggering the NotEmpty validation error message I see the message below.

```
File 'qhepstow_dblive.sql' exceeds the defined form size
```

How can I trigger the following error message when the file is not selected and avoid the once mentioned above?

This error message should be displayed when the file is not selected.

```
Please select a template file
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem. Hope it helps someone in the future.

The problem was with the sequence in which I was adding the validators to the file elemenet.

Changing the sequence to below solved the problem.

```
$file = $this->createElement('file', 'templateFile');
        $file->setAttrib('id', 'templateFile')
            ->setAttrib('class', 'form-control')
            ->setAttrib('placeholder', 'File containing template headers')
            ->setLabel('Template File <span class="glyphicons glyphicons-sheriffs_star requiredFlag"></span>')
            ->setDestination($destination)
            ->setRequired(true)
            ->addValidator('Count', false, 1)
            ->addValidator('NotEmpty', false)
            ->addValidator('Size', false, '15MB')
            ->addValidator("Extension", false, array('txt' ,'csv'))
            ->addFilter('StringTrim');
```